# How can I politely explain to my students that the texts in my course are all in English and it is their duty to read it nonetheless?

Tags: teaching, language, reading, syllabus

Eventually I grew tired of having to explain over and over why *all* my class material is in English. It's a mandatory course in Art History. I want to put some warning in my syllabus to minimize any arguments. The problem is how to do it politely, yet clearly.

The reasons are clear: there is no material in their native language for the courses I teach; obviously I cannot and will not translate the material; and it is their duty to read in English. I guess I cannot tell them straight that if they do not read English well they will not even understand classes well and will get low grades. I don't want to sound rude.

Is there a way to explain the situation, or is it better not to include such a written statement in a syllabus and keep things as they are?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the fact that it is their _duty_ to read in English? It is rather an interesting situation; in other countries (such as in Czech Republic) it is the other way around, with teaching in the native language being mandatory for a public school.

Comment: I do teach in their native language. It is mandatory that I do so. But all the texts are in English. There is simply no publication in my field in their native language.

Comment: Just for curiosity, is English an official requirement in their University? In mine, for example, we couldn't graduate before passing an English test

Comment: No, it's not an official requirement in the department I teach. But in the entrance exam, it is.

Comment: Why do you consider it rude to tell them up front that reading English is required?  It seems rude to *not* tell them up front.

Comment: Is this a normal situation in your institution? Are there other courses (other than foreign language, history ,and similar) that depend on foreign language texts?

Comment: Interesting discussion here. In Germany, there is a trend towards offering entire courses in English because of what [jakebeal writes](http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/34072/4140). I don't know whether there are legal requirements that a degree must be achievable with German-language courses. If so, this would be state law, since higher ed is the states' legal responsibility.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: in graduate math, much specialized literature only exists in English. For instance, I wouldn't know of a single German-language textbook on multiple complex variables or complex geometry. We used an English-language one that my (German) professor had written. Translations make little sense in such a specialized topic, where the *worldwide* market is already extremely small.

Comment: @StephanKolassa: My guess is that if anything, there is a legal requirement that a degree must be achievable *without* German-language courses, to allow for a flawless transition of European students across Bologna countries. (But, no, I don't really think such a *legal* requirement exists in Germany currently. Students are simply expected to be good enough at English to be able to attend any given course, no matter whether it's given in German or in English. At least, that is my impression from CS and probably all engineering disciplines.)

Comment: I'd think their grade on the first quiz on that material would explain it nicely.

Comment: @ChrisLively, actually it's not rude to tell them that; they just can't believe it when they see all readings are in English. Way into the semester, they still can't believe it.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan, the normal situation in my institution is: even if there is a better text in another language, they use what is available. Even if what you have in the local language is mediocre. Sometimes this attitude even extends to graduate degrees.

Comment: @jeremyjjbrown, yes, the first exam really does make things clear for them, but alas, I have the impression that their thought is, "Why on Earth is this a mandatory course"?

Comment: Is this an undergraduate or a graduate level course?

Comment: @Szabolcs, it's an undergraduate course.

Comment: Does your university have any policies on this?  Where I did my undergraduate, it would have been unacceptable and unreasonable to *require* fluency in English for an undergraduate course.  Many of the students would not have been able to keep up.  There were optional courses on modern topics for which most of the material was only available in English, but the instructor did provide all the notes that we needed in the local language.  At the graduate level it was made clear from the beginning that English is a requirement, so those who can't keep up need not apply.

Comment: I'm trying to make two points: 1. this really depends on the local situation, more detail is needed (e.g. where you're teaching) 2. if it wasn't made clear to them *at the time when they were admitted to the programme* that English is a *requirement*, then it's not reasonable for you to ask this for a mandatory course

Comment: @Szabolcs, you're right. Even I don't require fluency -- just reading comprehension. Yes, all my notes and presentations are in the local language. And yet, many complain. The situation is odd because there's no material but in English. In the end, I don't require English, but if they want to read...

Comment: @Joseph: If they are required to take the course to graduate *and* they were not aware that they needed to know English in order to do so then they really have a point. If you're saying they don't need to do the English readings in order to do well in the class then explicitly tell them so.

Comment: "obviously I cannot and will not translate the material".  Depending on your institution or location, you may *have to* develop your own teaching material (summary and synthesis of the existing English litterature). Books on advanced topics in mathematics are almost all in English, so French lecturers usually develop their own lecture notes. Actually, except during the first class to give additional references, most of my lecturers didn't bother to bring a book during "lectures".

Comment: For Art History, it may be necessary to use the books for illustrations, but supported by instruction language notes. As far as not translating the material is concerned, you are, in effect, requiring each student who does not know any English to find some way of getting a translation.

Comment: Once I took a math course at the University of Minnesota where the textbook was in French, although I never heard anything but English in the classroom.  I think some of my classmates were a bit alarmed.

Comment: If you are teaching in a language other than english then surely it IS your reponsibility to ensure a reliable translation of the texts into that language is available?

Comment: @JamesRyan: As discussed in various other comments and answers here, this very much seems to depend on the place and also the field. In some places and fields, a student who doesn't know English is not considered fit for studying at a university, no matter what language (some of) the courses are taught in.

Comment: Germany: my bi-lingual (E/D) daughter is studying maths bilingual D/E at a German uni. They are obliged to do some courses in each language. For one course I suggested she would have an advantage because her English is so good, she replied that no, no-one was going to the course because the lecturer, who has no German whatsoever, speaks English so badly that they can't understand him.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Of course, that is fine if it is made clear up front.  But if the course is mandatory and in a non-technical field, surely it should be passable in the taught language?

Comment: @JamesRyan: Again, that depends a lot on the context. Ability to read and write is not explicitly made clear up front, either, it is just assumed that students come with these skills. Likewise, while there are exceptions depending on the high school, in some places it is kind-of guaranteed that for almost every student, English is one of the foreign languages the student has learned at high school.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper If english was as common place as you suggest then there would be no reason for the course's official language not to be english.  If it is in another language because only most but not all students know english then it is entirely unreasonable and unprofessional to exclude them through laziness. If there is an additional requirement because of technical terms then that should be stated not assumed.

Comment: @JamesRyan: If English is a second language to the lecturer anyway, and everyone in the course understands <local language>, there is no reason not to give the course in <local language>, for the sake of convenience. Also, I find it peculiar how you see the "laziness" on the side of the lecturer when it's the students who do not learn English (or whatever non-local language might be suitable for the discipline in question). A part of university education means learning to gather knowledge autonomously, and relying on a lecturer spoon-feeding translated material is just the opposite of that.

Comment: @JamesRyan: Moreover, note that the respective students can always ask for a translation, if they really need one. It's not the lecturer's duty to foresee all exotic special cases that might arise.

Comment: **Please take extended conversation to [chat]**.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I agree that it makes sense to set expectations as early as possible.

I'd just put

> Note that all XXX for this course are in English.

in the syllabus. You should of course be *specific* as to what XXX is:

- Class slides
- Required reading
- Supplemental reading
- Lectures (you could have slides in English but speak the local language during the actual lecture)
- Quizzes
- Exams

If quizzes/exams are in English, you should also note whether students would be expected to *answer* in English.

Whether or not you also want to include the reasons for this is really up to how much space you have in the syllabus and whether there isn't anything more important to put there. I'd say that a warning might be a better use for the space:

> If your English is not up to reading/understanding/writing technical documents, this course likely is not a good fit for you.

Comment: Stephan, your first suggestion is nice. I had thought of something like that. The latter warning, however, would be fine only in optional courses. Although I would think twice before putting it in print, fearful that it would invoke upon me the wrath of faculty and students alike.

Comment: @Joseph: in an ideal world, for a compulsory course this warning would be pushed away from the course notes to the point where the decision is made that makes your course inevitable: "if your English is not up to reading technical documents, this subject likely is not a good fit for you", or "this university likely is not a good fit for you because there are compulsory courses in which strong English is required" if the course is compulsory for *all* undergraduates. As you say, though, even those who privately admit it's true might not want to say so in public, for political reasons.

Comment: From the comments, it sounds like the issue is broader than this particular syllabus question.  If the level of English proficiency required to complete required courses for the program is higher than the level required (and advertised) as a prerequisite for entering the program (or obtained from classes during the program), then either the classes need to be changed or the program entry requirements need to be changed.  Eventually the department must face the issue somehow.

Answer (score 24):

In many fields, you cannot be considered educated as an effective practitioner unless you know a particular language, because communications in that field are done in that language.

For example, once it was the case that one could not be a chemist without reading German, because all of the most critical work in chemistry was published in German.
Currently, it is extremely difficult to be a computer programmer without reading English: although interfaces and user documentation is often translated, the actual code and APIs for most programs is written in English.
Likewise, around the world all air traffic controllers are required to be proficient in English, as that is the agreed-upon fall-back language for air traffic control.

If the course you are teaching is in such a field, then explaining this fact can help students understand why it is important for them to read texts in English.  They may not be happy with this fact (and there may be good reasons to be unhappy about it), but understanding how language plays into their ability to put the material to use may be useful for getting them to accept its importance.

Comment: I once had a student in a summer prep class who wanted to study CompSci without knowing any English - he had had German, French, Latin and Spanish at school. I told him  he should use the time until the official start of the course to learn some basic english. He didn't, tried to start in summer, and sunk quickly, although his math grades were not bad and the bachelor course is taught in German. Everyone else dropped because of the math - he dropped because of the english...

Comment: @jakebeal, you are absolutely right. Every semester I try to do that, but after some years I came to terms with the fact that my arguments are not convincing. It's a mandatory course. They can't graduate without passing it. None of the other professors are like me. Some don't even speak English. The faculty voted for ending foreign language classes in the department. And yes, if I told what I teach, the need for foreign languages would be so obvious that most would comment that this situation is ridiculous: I teach History -- Art History and Middle East Studies.

Comment: @Joseph You should mention that you teach History in the question.  That put everything in a completely different perspective for me and I realize that some of the comments I wrote on your question don't apply.  I studied physics, meaning we had a smaller volume of material and could rely mostly on class notes.

Comment: I see a weakness in your argument: if English is an absolute necessity to work in a field, it means that English has to be learn somewhere before the graduation. It could be an independant English class, or a "English for Science/Engineer/History of Arts" class, or a class held in English. BUT it still need to be unambiguously agreed upon before registration in that class.

Comment: (-1) I think this is simply untrue. You need some English to do *research* in most fields but not merely to be an effective practitioner. Alexander's anecdote notwithstanding, there are in fact many computer programmers who know very little English.

Comment: @Relaxed: we see different anecdotes, but I've yet to meet *competent* programmers who can't read English (at least in Italy). So little technical documentation is translated decently (at least to Italian) that not reading English is a severe handicap (and Italians write mostly in English anyway, typically we aren't language nationalists). That might change depending on the national community in your subfield — say, Japan seems to have enough non-English-speaking Ruby programmers that I ran into Japanese-only information on internals.

Comment: @Blaisorblade Yes, there are obviously some languages in which no documentation is available (I would have thought Italian is not among them but I don't really know; I was thinking more about French and German) and it probably depends on the technology/area as well. And at least reading English is in any case an asset. But the claim that English is absolutely *necessary* is much more onerous. It's enough to note that some people manage without it to disprove it while the (undoubtedly large) number of people who can speak English and are computer programmers is hardly relevant.

Comment: @Relaxed My point is I've never met any non-English-reading competent programmer, at least for my definition of *competent*. I think, with Dijkstra, that programmers are like neurosurgeons, so I'm not sure they produce "value" unless they're very good. EDIT: but of course, that definition of competent is highly questionable, and I don't have the needed evidence to be 100% sure of it myself.

Comment: @Blaisorblade “Effective” or “competent” are doing all the work here but that's not a reasonable definition. It's simply a “no true scotsman” argument.

Answer (score 23):

Could you clarify where you are teaching and at what level?

A young undergraduate student might consider it "unfair" if he or she fails your course because of insufficient English skills. A more mature student will understand that you're offering preparation for real life.

A professor of mine once told us halfway through the class that "the remainder would be held in the international language of science, broken American English." He expected us to get the technical terms right and the rest of our sentences understandable. Proper pronounciation was optional.

Back to your question, tell your students that you expect reading comprehension of technical literature. They don't have to speak English, and they don't have to write beautiful sentences.

Comment: Hopefully, nobody has failed my course because of  language skills -- many students just use it as an excuse. And you're absolutely right about the technical terms.

Comment: +1 for `"the international language of science, broken American English"`

Answer (score 13):

If the course is mandatory I think, in fairness to the students, you should go one of two routes:

- Make the English reading requirement formal and written. It should be included in the prospectus for any program that requires your course. There should be a suitable English course that can be taken before your course, and that course, or equivalent skill, should be a stated prerequisite.
- Make it possible to get the top grade in your course without reading any English. That would mean including in the course notes material that an English-reading student could get from text books. The text books would be at the most optional extras for students who want to go beyond your course, not required material. Given the additional information that the subject is Art History, you could still require the text books for their illustrations, but write notes that tell the students what they are looking at.

Whether English-reading is required for the program seems to be a policy decision that should be made by the faculty as a whole.

=======================================================================

There is a third, intermediate, option. Campaign to make the course an option rather than mandatory. In that case, the English requirement would only need to be documented in materials the students use to make their optional course selections. It does not need to be part of the requirements for the program as a whole.

Answer (score 5):

I think you can simply mention the main references and course materials at the beginning of the class.

On the other hand, I believe, it is the job of an instructor, to present the material in the official language of his/her institution is such a way that without additional materials, the students can well follow the course and to be able to successfully pass the exams.

André Weil once said

```
The student's note-book should be his principal text-book.
```

In Mathematics (and I believe in many other domains) there are still some domains in which one cannot really be an expert without knowing French and German. But just because the materials of my domain is not in the official language of my institution (for example they are in French or German), doesn't mean I can force the students to learn them. It is my job to teach them and present them in the official language of my institution.

Answer (score 4):

I think you certainly need to make crystal clear at the very beginning of the class that a reading knowledge of English is required.  If possible, it should be clear even earlier than that - perhaps mentioned in the course description that students read when deciding to register for the class.  That way, students who do not have the necessary skills can sign up for some other class instead.  By the time the class starts, it may be more difficult for them to do so.

Another option may be to require an appropriate English class as a prerequisite (which can be waived for students who already have sufficient fluency).

If this is a mandatory course, then you need to have a discussion with your department as to whether your use of English materials is reasonable.  They have an interest in running a program which students can actually pass.  If your colleagues decide that this is not reasonable, then either you will have to change the way you teach it, or someone else will have to teach it instead of you.

Comment: I'd rather not deal with the faculty. Many things are not reasonable. For example, this semester "the faculty" have found a way to erase all fails from a course (Honors Thesis, which is required): school transcripts of all students who fail won't show that they have failed that course (some students 2 or even 3 times). That is their concept of "reasonable".

Comment: @Joseph: That sounds unpleasant, but to be honest, I don't think your idea of "do what I want without asking them" is really the answer.  It's unprofessional.  If you can't live with the decisions your colleagues make, then maybe you ought to consider looking for a different job.

Comment: @Joseph The only way to make the situation fair to the students that lies entirely in your own hands is to change your course to remove the need to read English. That may be a lot of work. You would have to write up in the language of instruction, and include in your course notes, all material that the students need to know to ace your course. Not just pass it. Ace it. Forcing a poor grade on someone because they lack an unstated prerequisite would be unfair.

Answer (score 2):

Try something similar to the following:

> This course, and all required reading, will be presented in English.  If you need assistance understanding any course materials, please see your counselor or [other university resources for ESL students].

This makes it clear that everything will be presented in a specific language, and indicates that the class and teacher are not the appropriate people to work with students lacking English proficiency.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the country/culture in which you teach, it might simply not be possible. It's easy to assume the “everybody speaks English” or that “students will need it anyway” to make your life easier but often it's not true.

Without starting a debate on language planning, it's not obvious to me why it should be impossible to learn art history and enter a career in teaching, become a museum curator or whatever it is your students could do after taking your course, certainly if they speak another major European language.

Personally, I speak several languages and would certainly recommend learning English to anybody who asks but I also know people doing decent work without knowing it, even in supposedly internationalized and English-dominated fields like computer science. It's useful and common to be sure but outside of academic research it's not vital and I don't think it would be fair for me to deny people an education and career (or, from another perspective, to limit the talent pool in the country) on that basis alone.

If you teach in a country where English is not a general requirement in higher education or there is an expectation that lecturers provide their own teaching material, then it is in fact your job to enable learning in the local language and there might be no way to prevent students from perceiving your not doing so as unfair, rude and lazy.

Comment: As for the "expectation that lecturers provide their own teaching material", there is none, except that the professor make available the readings, usually by photocopying the books and articles and leaving it in a "room" where students get a folder and pay on a page-by-page basis.

Comment: @Joseph I changed that to “or”. You still haven't provided many details so we all have to speculate a bit. But in any case my main point is that you can't assume that students will or ought to find this requirement reasonable or that finding a clever way to express it will put all arguments to rest.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking how to explain things politely. I don't think it's that complicated. Simply state:

"All required reading for this course will be in English."

There's nothing rude about that in terms of voice.

However, you don't give us enough background information to understand the context. If this college doesn't teach all courses in English, and doesn't require proficiency in English, or anything similar, then no matter what your voice, students are going to see this as a rather rude obstruction in their curriculum. This would be a failing of the particular school you are teaching in. They need to make it clear to students that there may be classes requiring all reading in English prior to them committing to the program.

Answer (score 0):

I can't judge your colleagues just from your observations, but maybe I agree with you. Nonetheless, students are suffering (though not terribly) from this.

Since you wrote that you can't really discuss this with the faculty, I think the possible solutions are:

- List the requirement anyway, if your colleagues won't bother you for that. Some students will be annoyed *and* in their right to be annoyed (at the situation, if not necessarily at you).
- To improve things for students, if you can, get faculty to make your course optional, and possibly to accept at least an optional English course for credit in the degree.

  That still implies discussion with colleagues, but it doesn't require
  them to do extra work (say, learn English), so they might be more
  willing to accept. Moreover, it's the easiest solution which is
  actually fair to students. That might reduce your studentship to
  people who care and accept the requirement. For you, that might be good (you'd get more motivated students) or not (if too few students pick your course and colleagues get nervous about it).
- I don't know really enough to say this, but if it's reasonable for you, you might want to change to another department where you can work with your colleagues rather than against them. From your tone, it sounds like it would avoid you quite some annoyance *and* make both departments better for students. I've seen or suffered, as a students, enough departments where communication between professors was visibly dysfunctional. Of course, I don't think anybody can demand such an extreme solution from you.

Answer (score 0):

I second o.m.'s remark about the language of science being broken English -- and I would stress the **advantage** of this fact to the students (at least in the first lesson). Science isn't something that is done only in and for one country, e.g., German Science, or US Science, etc.

Sure, there are national organizations and differences in universities between countries, but the findings themselves are usually applicable and discussed internationally (with all intercultural differences, at least most of the work in psychology is widely applicable, probably all of the 'hard sciences', and I'm guessing that even if local art history is discussed, theories are probably internationally applicable).

So, being able to (at least) understand English allows a student to listen into that discussion.